# How do I instruct Entity Framework to select the correct relationship between two tables with multiple foreign keys between them?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have an entity framework setup which has been generated using the database first approach. In it I have a User table and a profile table.

```
User
- UserId
- ProfileId

Profile
- ProfileId
- {unimportant profile details}
- ModifiedOn
- CreatedOn
```

In each of these tables the Ids are their primary keys. The issue is that there are 3 Foreign Key relationships between the two tables.

1. A User Has A Profile (User.FK_User_Profile User.ProfileId == Profile.ProfileId)
2. A Profile was Created by a User (Profile.FK_UserCreatedBy Profile.CreatedBy == User.UserId)
3. A Profile was Modified by a User (Profile.FK_UserModifiedBy Profile.ModifiedBy == User.UserId)

This all works fine in the database. Unfortunately, when I try to access the edmx generated from this with the following Linq query:

```
databaseContext.User.Where(u => u.UserID == SOMEGUID)
            .Select(p => p.Profile.FirstOrDefault())
```

the generated sql is this:

```
SELECT projected details
  FROM ( SELECT
    [Extent1].UserId as UserId,
    [Extent2].ProfileId as ProfileId,
    [Other fields],
    FROM  [dbo].[User] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Profile] AS [Extent2] ON *[Extent1].[UserID] = [Extent2].[ModifiedBy]*
    WHERE [Extent1].[ProfileID] = efGeneratedId
  )  AS [Project1]
```

The problem is that Left Outer Join criteria. Instead of joining on

```
Extent1.UserId = Extent2.UserId
```

it's joining on

```
Extent1.UserId = Extent2.ModifiedBy
```

This results in the Linq retrieving all users which modified the profile, rather than the profile that the user has.

How do I instruct EF to map this query, or more likely these relationships, correctly?

Comment: can you add the definitions of classes User and Profile? what attributes are you using in properties?

Comment: Please show edmx generated. If an user has 1 profile then the navigation property you are using is wrong, as you are doing firstordefault which is for collection not for navigation property (I mean Profile prop is a collection so it's representing one of the 1:N profile to user relation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't include any info about edmx generated, I will try to guess..:
The model for those tables should produce something like this on User class:

```
int ProfileId {get; set;}
Profile Profile {get; set;} //->An user has A profile
ICollection<Profile> ProfileX {get; set;} //CreatedBy
ICollection<Profile> ProfileY {get; set;} //ModifiedBy
```

According to the Sql you posted, the "Profile.FirstOrDefault" of your linq is the "ProfileY" collection of my example.

You should adjust edmx properties naming and use the one representing the User has A profile relation, which shouldn't be a collection

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction. The edmx did generate a Profile, Profile1, and Profile2. Rather than Profile using the FK_User_Profile key, as expected, it's using the FK_Profile_UserModified_By key. Profile1 is using the correct FK_User_Profile key. Thanks.